# how i show all the day of the month in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table and i would  like to show all the days of month in my table header fields like Monday, Tuesday , ...., Sunday, is there someone who can help me.
i'm using cakephp v 2.0, and i want to use helpers if it's posssible

```
<table>
<thead>
<th><div class="nameday"></div></th>
<th ><div class="Mistitle"><?php echo $this->Form->input('Missiontitle',array('label'=>false)); ?></div></th>

<?php

for($i=0;$i<$NumOfDays;$i++){ 
$thedate = $i+1 .'-'.$month.'-'.$year ;
if (in_array($i+1, $weekend)){ ?>
<th><div class="input-disabled">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('dat.Dates.',array('value'=> $i+1,'label'=>false ,'readonly'=>'readonly' ));?>
        </div>
    </th></thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

in 
thanks in advance .

Comment: Please show us any code you have worked so far.

Comment: Could you show us how you **want** your HTML to look like? Also, you have to wrap the THs in a TR!